# why 404 after ng build?

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, maven

I have an angular/spring boot app.  Normally I use maven to build both using *mvn clean install* from the parent dir.  That packages up the front and back ends into single jar file.  Then I run that jar file with *java -jar appname.jar*.  This works fine most of the time.  But every so often, the angular front end stops updating the changes I make.

I googled this a while back and the solution was to do `ng build --output-hashing=all`.  This usually works, but not this time.  Now I'm seeing 404 error.  Seems there is some resource its not finding.

> 2021-09-08 08:33:46.520 DEBUG 93888 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
> o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to
> ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["classpath:/META-INF/resources/",
> "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/",
> "/"] 2021-09-08 08:33:46.528 DEBUG 93888 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
> o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
> 2021-09-08 08:33:46.529 DEBUG 93888 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
> o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND

Thinking some resource might be missing, I tried *npm install* and *ng build*, but same result.

If I go back to the master branch, build it, go back to the dev branch, build it, then the 404 goes away but I'm back to the original problem.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to delete the *dist* folder, then do a *ng build*, then do a *mvn clean install*.  Its working now.

Answer (score 0):

try using base href while using ng build `ng build --prod --base-href './'`
base href will change based on your app context. i.e it could be './app' or './myapp/app' , check from console the difference in path and add it in context

Comment: I got a strange error when I ran that: Unknown option: '-d'.  That option is not even referenced!